# sql-server: Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server

I receive this syntax error when I execute the following query. Any suggestions how to fix it?

**EDIT**

The query is created dynamically, the size of the query that runs is >8000...

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
SELECT TS.* , --comma added
       (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [4501001], 103) AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501001]'
        FROM   form.AG_VISDATE
        WHERE  pid = TS.pid
               AND COALESCE(visid, '') = 'U1'),
       (SELECT [4501004] AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501004]'
        FROM   form.AG_VISDATE
        WHERE  pid = TS.pid
               AND COALESCE(visid, '') = 'U1')
```

I added the ',' after `TS.*` but now I receive these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TS'.

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole query?

Comment: Try adding a comma after `TS.*`. The subqueries must return a scalar value when executed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these statements will work

```
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [4501001], 103) AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501001]'
        FROM   form.AG_VISDATE
        WHERE  pid = TS.pid
               AND COALESCE(visid, '') = 'U1')

   (SELECT [4501004] AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501004]'
    FROM   form.AG_VISDATE
    WHERE  pid = TS.pid
           AND COALESCE(visid, '') = 'U1')
```

as the WHERE clause will fail because TS is not defined anywhere

Both statements could be re-written into one

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, [4501001], 103) AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501001]',
       [4501004] AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501004]'
FROM   form.AG_VISDATE
WHERE  pid = <SOMETHING> AND
       COALESCE(visid, '') = 'U1'
```

It isn't clear what you are trying to do. You would be better including your schema, test data and what output you want

Comment: Apologies, there was an error in the syntax of my statement. Please try it now

Comment: Also deleted my original comments as they make no sense against your edited code

Answer (score 0):

It could be the convert.  It appears you want to convert a date to a string.

```
DECLARE @test date = '2017-10-13'
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @test, 103) AS 'AG_VISDATE.U1.[4501001]'
```